# Gravação de voz com MediaRecorder Android Studio

Tags: android

Estou trabalhando em um projeto com gravação de voz, estou com meio caminho andado, já estou com o gravador funcionando e salvando a gravação conforme o código a baixo, porem estou com alguns problemas:  1º não consigo criar uma pasta para salvar os áudios para depois exibir, fica todos os audios no diretório raiz, 2º não consigo listar os áudios na listView, 3º não faço a menor ideia de como deletar os áudios depois de criados e exibidos na ListView. segue o código do  gravador .java e XML. OBS: não vou colocar o codigo do exibir da listView porque não tem nada implementado.

```
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Random;

import static android.Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO;
import static android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;

public class Gravador extends AppCompatActivity {

Button buttonStart, buttonStop, buttonPlayLastRecordAudio, buttonStopPlayingRecording ;
String AudioSavePathInDevice = null;
MediaRecorder mediaRecorder ;
Random random ;
String RandomAudioFileName = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP";
public static final int RequestPermissionCode = 1;
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_gravador);

    buttonStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    buttonStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    buttonPlayLastRecordAudio = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    buttonStopPlayingRecording = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);

    buttonStop.setEnabled(false);
    buttonPlayLastRecordAudio.setEnabled(false);
    buttonStopPlayingRecording.setEnabled(false);

    random = new Random();

    buttonStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if(checkPermission()) {

                AudioSavePathInDevice = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + CreateRandomAudioFileName(5) + "AudioRecording.3gp";

                MediaRecorderReady();

                try {
                    mediaRecorder.prepare();
                    mediaRecorder.start();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                buttonStart.setEnabled(false);
                buttonStop.setEnabled(true);

                Toast.makeText(Gravador.this, "Recording started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else {

                requestPermission();

            }

        }
    });

    buttonStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            mediaRecorder.stop();

            buttonStop.setEnabled(false);
            buttonPlayLastRecordAudio.setEnabled(true);
            buttonStart.setEnabled(true);
            buttonStopPlayingRecording.setEnabled(false);

            Toast.makeText(Gravador.this, "Recording Completed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });

    buttonPlayLastRecordAudio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) throws IllegalArgumentException, SecurityException, IllegalStateException {

            buttonStop.setEnabled(false);
            buttonStart.setEnabled(false);
            buttonStopPlayingRecording.setEnabled(true);

            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

            try {
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(AudioSavePathInDevice);
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            mediaPlayer.start();

            Toast.makeText(Gravador.this, "Recording Playing", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });

    buttonStopPlayingRecording.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            buttonStop.setEnabled(false);
            buttonStart.setEnabled(true);
            buttonStopPlayingRecording.setEnabled(false);
            buttonPlayLastRecordAudio.setEnabled(true);

            if(mediaPlayer != null){

                mediaPlayer.stop();
                mediaPlayer.release();

                MediaRecorderReady();

            }

        }
    });
}

public void MediaRecorderReady(){

    mediaRecorder=new MediaRecorder();

    mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);

    mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);

    mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);

    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(AudioSavePathInDevice);

}

public String CreateRandomAudioFileName(int string){

    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder( string );

    int i = 0 ;
    while(i < string ) {

        stringBuilder.append(RandomAudioFileName.charAt(random.nextInt(RandomAudioFileName.length())));

        i++ ;
    }
    return stringBuilder.toString();

}

private void requestPermission() {

    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Gravador.this, new String[]{WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, RECORD_AUDIO}, RequestPermissionCode);

}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case RequestPermissionCode:
            if (grantResults.length > 0) {

                boolean StoragePermission = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                boolean RecordPermission = grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

                if (StoragePermission && RecordPermission) {

                    Toast.makeText(Gravador.this, "Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(Gravador.this,"Permission Denied",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            }

            break;
    }
}

public boolean checkPermission() {

    int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    int result1 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), RECORD_AUDIO);

    return result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && result1 == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
}
```

}

XML do Gravador

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/mic_pic"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Record"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
    />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="STOP"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Play"
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="STOP PLAYING RECORDING "
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bom voce tem mais de uma duvida entao vou tentar te ajudar em passos:

1. Salvar o audio em uma pasta especifica:

Segundo essa [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25780686/3473971) do SO gringo:

```
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/suapasta");

if (f.isDirectory()) {
        //Seu codigo caso o "suapasta" seja um diretorio

} else {

        // cria um objeto File pro diretorio pai
        File wallpaperDirectory = new File("/sdcard/Wallpaper/");
        // cria a pasta caso seja necessario
        wallpaperDirectory.mkdirs();
       // cria o objeto File pro output
       File outputFile = new File(wallpaperDirectory, filename);
       // agora adiciona o OutputStream no seu arquivo
       FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

}
```

Esse codigo checa se o local onde voce quer salvar eh uma pasta (nao vai ser na primeira vez que salvar, ou caso apague os dados do dispositivo) e caso seja, voce ja salva direto como faria na pasta raiz, senao ele cria a pasta pra voce e ai vc salva o arquivo (recomendo um metodo auxiliar pra salvar pra evitar a duplicidade de codigo)

2. Mostrar no listview

Essa parece mais ser uma pergunta de desconhecimento de como funciona o ListView do que ter a ver com audio, entao te recomendo fortemente dar uma lida na documentacao do ListView (a nao ser que seja um requerimento usar o ListView, tambem recomendo fortemente, mas fortemente  mesmo, dar uma olhada no RecyclerView ao inves do ListView)

Segue a documentacao:

[ListView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html?hl=pt-br)

[Como Criar listas e Cards](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html?hl=pt-br)

Mas a ideia basica por cima de forma resumida, eh que voce precisa criar um layout pra cada item da sua lista, ter uma lista de objetos de audio (ou de uma classe container com mais informacoes sobre o audio) que vai ser passada pro adapter, criar um adapter que relaciona o seu layout com cada item da lista (procure por ListView/RecyclerView adapter que encontra muita coisa no Google) e acredito que voce tambem quer relacionar cada audio com um elemento da lista, isso eh facinho de fazer no adapter quando voce entende o conceito.

3. Deletar os audios

Bom, nao entendi muito bem essa duvida, pois se voce deletar eles nao vai conseguir usa-los no ListView pra tocar, entao se puder deixe um comentario explicando melhor o que vc quis dizer com isso que eu edito.

Desculpa se nao respondi todas as duvidas mas era uma pergunta bem extensa, espero ter ajudado

Comment: Opa muito obrigado pela dica, sou novo na área de desenvolvimento Mobile, questao de deletar seria depois de já estar listando os áudios, ou seja, aparecendo todos na lista, quero deletar determinado áudio que gravei e que não quero mais usar ou nao quero mais que que apareça na lista. Outra questão é como eu poderia colocar um nome antes de salvar o Áudio?